Umlauts in mathmode using the textfont
How can I use the "ä" "ö" and "ü" from the textfont in mathmode?
I want to be able to just type "ä" "ö" or "ü" as I would in textmode.
I've figured out how to change letters and digits looking at the mathastext.sty and even managed to find a way for the eszett/sharp s "ß":
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[scale=.85]{tgheros}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DeclareSymbolFont{myfont}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n} 

\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{myfont}{97}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\myss}{\mathalpha}{myfont}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\umlauta}{\mathalpha}{myfont}{228}

\let\ogss\ss
\renewcommand{\ss}{\ifmmode\myss\else\ogss\fi}

\begin{document}
aäß

$aäß$

$\umlauta$
\end{document}

I don't want to define a new macro as I did in my minimal example above. I want to just be able to just type "ä" and get the desired effect.
I think the problem I'm having with these umlauts is, that ä is evaluated as \"a or something similar and \" is a macro unlike \ss for example.

you are using the 7bit OT1 math italic font which isn't really set up for textual unlauts and doesn't have the pre-formed composite glyphs that a T1 encoded font has. (and the math double dot accent isn't really the same thing. The usual thing to do is use the text font and $\text{aäß}...$ but there are alternatives.

Hm, \usepackage{fonttable} showed the needed composite glyph for "ä" at position 228 in the OT1 encoding. The other two "options" are known to me but (as you implied) are no solution for what I'm trying to achive.

OT1 doesn't have 228 positions. It only has 128. 7 bit.

as @cfr says, an OT1 encoded font should not have any entries above 127

@DavidCarlisle tell that to fonttable :-).

@cfr well yes given that all fonts other than cm typically make ot1 by subsetting from a more sensible encoding, it's not uncommon for glyphs to be sneaked in, but as you know they are unreliable and will change from font to font

@DavidCarlisle so it is expected to typeset a table for t1?

Well I'm not even sure which encoding tgheros actually uses.
Everything Symbol I tried worked with \DeclareSymbolFont{myfont}{OT1}{qhv}{m}{n}  or \DeclareSymbolFont{myfont}{T1}{qhv}{m}{n}  when using the respective slot fonttable showed me. Does LaTeX map between these different encodings or does that mean the font is available in both encodings?

ot1 fonts are supposed to be 8bit fonts (as that'd the tfm format) but with the top half empty. If a font isn't empty in the top half you just aren't supposed to notice:-)

@DavidCarlisle but fonttable isn't supposed to print the raw font encoding. if I set up a virtual font, it should print the reencoded table. that might mean it is taking characters from several fonts. it might include constructed characters etc. but q-rm.enc is 8bit. it isn't the same as q-ec.enc, but it contains the same number of characters.

@DavidCarlisle but I suppose I can't really complain the font lies about q-rm.enc being OT1.

@PeterMaier this font is available in several encodings, including both ot1 and t1. however, ot1 is not actually ot1.

@cfr Is there an easy way to find all encodings a font is available in?

@PeterMaier officially, I guess read the documentation. but what I'd do is look in the latex directory e.g. tex/latex/tex-gyre and look for all the files named <something>qhv.fd. The <something>s indicate the font encodings eg ot1qhv.fd, t1qhv.fd etc.

@PeterMaier Welcome to TeX.SE, do you want all the text to be in sanserif font family, am I correct?

@MadyYuvi yes, you are correct.

If you don't want constructed accents, you need T1 encoding.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=.85]{tgheros}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ä}{\ifmmode\umlauta\else\"a\fi}
\newunicodechar{ß}{\ifmmode\mathss\else\ss\fi}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\DeclareSymbolFont{myfont}{T1}{qhv}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{myfont}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathss}{\mathalpha}{myfont}{255}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\umlauta}{\mathalpha}{myfont}{228}

\begin{document}

aäß

$aäß$

\end{document}

Repeat for the other accented letters. Consulting the T1 font table would be useful.

If you want to avoid the warnings, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724179/4427

Thanks! Declaring a new unicode char solved the problems I ran into.
